# Trouble with browserify and express

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass data from my web application to mySQL database, and I need the following requires:
-mysql,
-express,
-body-parser
When I run the javascript code by using $node main.js, there is no problem.
Now, when I run the directory with $http-server ./, in the browser it prints out that require is undefined.
The directory has index.html and style.css files.
Thus, I installed browserify, and did $browserify main.js > bundle.js, and included the bundle.js file as a script in html file.
I even included the dependecies in package.json
However, I still get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
and the line it points out is to this line

```
var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
```

along with other lines

Answer (score 0):

Browersify can transpile JavaScript to remove the need for the browser to support a module system.

It can't polyfill APIs that depend on features that are available to Node.js but are not available in browsers (such the networking features required to connect to MySQL or run an HTTP server). Those **need** the JS to be run under Node.js and not a browser.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response  Since Browserify seems to not work, Is there a way I can implement these features on my browser?

Comment: @Isaiah — No. See the second paragraph of the answer.